# Ionic1 with compare face aws service

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition, aws-sdk-js

I want to integrate the Amazon rekognition, compare face api in my ionic project. Can anyone suggest any sample or way to that.
I am trying on simple JS but getting an authorization error.

Comment: you try watch example project this [ionic-aws-rekognition](https://github.com/echim/ionic-aws-rekognition)

Comment: Not yet, will try it today. thanks in adv.

Comment: Are you still having problem integrating Rekognition into your ionic app? Can you share sample code you have tried and sample error you are facing in-order to assist you further?